# Is Stored javascript in mongodb, atomic?

Tags: mongodb, transactions

If I call the following stored-function from server:
Assume that, insertation of bEntity failed. In this situtation, does added aEntity roll back to the its old state?

```
function areYouAnAtomicOperation(x)
{
db.aEntity.insert ({a:x});
db.bEntity.insert ({b:x});
db.cEntity.insert ({c:x});
}
```

Any method, for making this function atomic in mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not atomic. Here is a list of [atomic operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations).

If it's really really really *important* you can manually emulate [two-phase commit](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/two-phase+commit) semantics but be warned that it's really *complicated*.

If transactions are important, you better use some other database (an RDBMS?) which provides it.